# Verb mit Bedeutung „etwas als nutzlos/überflüssig erkennen“?

Tags: verb, single-word-request

Gibt es ein deutsches Verb das so viel wie *etwas als nutzlos/überflüssig erkennen* (z.B. ein Dokument, einen Gegenstand o.ä.) bedeutet?

Comment: Servus und willkommen beim Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Du kannst eine [tour] dieser Seite nehmen. Fragen darüber, wie sie funktioniert, beantwortet dir das [help].

Comment: Nein, wäre meine Antwort, aber so ein Nein ist schwer zu belegen.

Comment: Ich glaube auch nicht, dass wir so ein Verb haben. Das würde viel zu viel Staub ansetzen, weil es so wenig benutzt wird (oder möglicherweise hatten wir mal eins,  haben es aber als nutzlos/überflüssig erkannt?)

Comment: nutzlosifizieren ;-)

Comment: _(weg)rationalisieren_ möglicherweise

Answer (score 3):

**Disqualifizieren**.
Hauptsächlich zwar für Personen gebraucht, aber möglich wäre es.

> Dieses Dokument ist disqualifiziert (für/zum ...)!

Comment: +1 und noch als Ergänzung die Bedeutung aus dem Duden: "(bildungssprachlich, seltener) für untauglich, für nicht qualifiziert erklären"

Comment: Verwandt: _abqualifizieren_. Ähnlich: _abstempeln_

Answer (score 3):

Ich schlage für Gegenstände oder Verfahren eines von diesen vor:

- ausmustern
- aussondern
- aussortieren
- aussieben
- verwerfen

Diese werden typischerweise oder sogar überwiegend dafür verwendet, um die auf das Erkennen der Nutzlosigkeit folgende Handlung zu bezeichnen (wegwerfen, zu den Akten legen, etc.), vor allem *aussondern* hat aber eine breitere Bedeutung.

Comment: Die meisten deiner Vorschläge haben über das bloße *Erkennen* der Nutzlosigkeit auch gleich noch das *Verwerfen* als Bedeutung. Nahe dran, aber mMn nicht getroffen.